# How can I add in Wordpress a custom php first page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom **index.php** (with **images css**) which is **a soap client**.

In this index.php I have a Send button which connects to the soap server and searches for results.This works fine!

If the results validate the users then **I want to redirect them automatically to the first page of a Wordpress site**.

my wordpress lets say is

[www.wpdemo.com](http://www.wpdemo.com)

**Where** and **how** should I place my custom index.php(included images and css) in order to work **like a first page validation for users**???

It dont know where to place the code... In the theme ? Do I have to change something in database?

Thans for your answers mates..

Comment: try in theme's index.php file. This file is default home page of wordpress.

Comment: include css,js,validation in wp-content/templates/any_template/header.php file.

Comment: which template you use ?

Comment: How can we access the `index.php` file via URL?

Comment: When you came to the site with known url you launch the core index.php, which starts the bootstrap script, that, after tons of magic, includes the theme index.php or home.php file, or any other depending on a url you came with. Technically: root index.php file launch anyway.

Comment: For those who asked I am using the Modernizer Theme for Wordpress

Comment: I have index2.php as custom page. How should I write the htaccess in order to redirect people into index.php without having a redirect problem ?                                                            
                                                           RewriteEngine on

Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/wpdemo/index2.php [r=307,NC]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use your current "Active" wordpress template's **home.php** (create one if missing) or **index.php** file. Please consider that home.php has got a priority over index.php in bootstrap script.

For better understanding the wordpress templates hierarchy, please visit [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

Hope it hepls,

-Cheers!